# how to separate image using color channel in python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Hello I want to separate an object based it's color into a new image using python PIL

but I don't quite get the gasp of it. I'm still new with python.

what I already done is a code from matlab and it works

```
G = imread('x.png');
L = G;
for i=1:217 #this is image height
    for j=1:286 #this is image width
        for k=1:3 #this is color RGB channel
            if(L(i,j,2) < 174) #if green value is under 174
                L(i,j,k) = L(i,j,k);
            else
                L(i,j,k) = 256; #change to white
            end

            if(L(i,j,3) < 174) #if blue value is under 174
                L(i,j,k) = L(i,j,k);
            else
                L(i,j,k) = 256; #change to white
            end
        end
    end
end
imshow(L)
```

Can I get a proper explanation about how you do it using python PIL ?

thank you very much

**edit :**

What I'm trying to do is something like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tRd1.jpg

Then the result is this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZP8D.jpg

Comment: Please describe the specific "separation" effect you want from this.  The only active statements you have drive blue & green components max saturation +1 -- *not* "white" --  if the pixel is already past about 68% saturation.  It doesn't touch the red component.

Comment: im sorry, I've edited the post.

Comment: Please also repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  "Figure out what this code does, and teach me how to do it in Python" is seriously out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: yes, thankyou very much. i can use this for reference on other subject. thanks for willing to answer it even thought my question is not following the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very easy way to do it using PIL/Pillow:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Load image and ensure it is RGB (not palette)
im = Image.open('circles.jpg').convert('RGB')

# Make into Numpy array so we can do fast, vectorised operations
na = np.array(im)

# Make a mask, which is True wherever Blue channel is high, False elsewhere - see #1 below
mBlueHi = na[...,2] >= 174

# Likewise for Green channel - see #2 below
mGreenHi = na[...,1] >= 174

# In our original image "na", anywhere the Green or Blue mask is set, make it white
na[mGreenHi | mBlueHi] = [255,255,255]

# Make back into PIL Image and save
Image.fromarray(na).save('result.png')
```

[image]

Note #1: The image is stored in a 3 dimensional array, height x width x RGB channels. Red is in channel 0, so it is `na[:,:,0]` and `na[...,0]` is shorthand for that same thing.

Note #2: Green is in the second channel starting from index 0, so the green pixels can be addressed using `na[:,:,1]` or equally `na[...,1]`

Note that JPEG is lossy and often a poor choice for intermediate files in image processing because it changes values to make files smaller. Consider using PNG which is lossless.